# "Fullscreen is unavailable" embedding YouTube videos as iframe in QWebEngineView

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview

I'm trying to embed a youtube video in a QWebEngineView, the video loads fine but the fullscreen button is disabled with this message "Fullscreen is unavailable" even thought the embed code does have "allowfullscreen"

Code snippet:

```
web = QWebEngineView()
htmlString = """
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/L0MK7qz13bU?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
             """
web.setHtml(htmlString, QUrl(baseUrl))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable the full screen it is necessary to enable the [FullScreenSupportEnabled](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginesettings.html#setAttribute) attribute and accept the [fullScreenRequested](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#fullScreenRequested) order of the page.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    web = QWebEngineView()
    web.settings().setAttribute(QWebEngineSettings.FullScreenSupportEnabled, True)
    web.page().fullScreenRequested.connect(lambda request: request.accept())
    baseUrl = "local"
    htmlString = """
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/L0MK7qz13bU?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
             """
    web.setHtml(htmlString, QUrl(baseUrl))

    web.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: btw, i'm seeing this warnings in PyCharm console, any idea what this means? "[20068:5672:1031/203943.715:ERROR:gl_context_wgl.cc(78)] Could not share GL contexts."

Comment: Those are Chromium warnings, the backend that Qt uses for QWebEngineView, is telling you that some things are not supported, but they are not errors. These are the same messages generated by google-chrome, mozilla, etc. if you run it from the console.

Comment: Thanks much again!